# VSTO excel AddIn auto update

Tags: vsto, visual-studio-2019, auto-update, excel-addins

I am trying to build auto update excel add in using click once deployment. I am stuck at below error

"The customization cannot be installed because another version is currently installed and cannot be upgraded from this location. To install this version of the customization, first use Add or Remove Programs to uninstall this program: M61AddIn. Then install the new customization from the following location: "

**I tired several things**

1. I am not trying to install/update a VSTO excel AddIn on the same machine where I have developed it
2. The update mode is set to "Every time the customization runs".

How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those want to know.how did i finished this task.Below things helped me

1. **Build events**

Added below line in visual studio build events

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\M61AddInExcel /v Manifest /t REG_SZ /d <install url>to /f
```

2. Added self-signing certificate provided by visual studio and installed this certificate on client machine
3. Publish settings are as below
   [image]